# Is it possible to Subscribe to Change Events without View All Permission

Tags: lightning-web-components, platform-event, change-data-capture

Scenario: I am currently making an lwc application and that app is subscribed in a ChangeEvent. The app is for user without 'view all' permission to the object. And since the user do not have view all permission, Change Event don't seem to fire for that user. Is there a way for that user (except ticking 'view' all permission) to listen to Change event?

Answer (score 0):

As per the [standard documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.change_data_capture.meta/change_data_capture/cdc_security_perms.htm), there should not be any way to fire change event without the necessary permission.

[image]

**This is how it works:**

For the standard /data/ChangeEvents channel and custom channels, user permissions are enforced on event delivery. Users can subscribe to the /data/ChangeEvents channel or to any custom channel regardless of their entity permissions. Users receive only change events associated with entities for which they have the necessary permissions and don't receive change events they don't have permissions for. If permissions change after subscription, the changes are enforced immediately and don’t require resubscription.

For the single-entity standard channels, which include change events for one standard or custom object, user permissions are enforced initially on subscription. If users don't have sufficient permissions for the corresponding object, the subscription is denied and an error is returned. If permissions change after successful subscription and users no longer have access to the entity, they stop receiving the corresponding change events.